# Метод execute vk возвращает Runtime error occurred during code invocation: too many operations

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Прошу помощи с ошибкой too many operations. В параметре code пытаюсь делать не более 25 запросов к методу groups.getMembers. В группах до 1000 участников работает, а где более 1000 падает ошибка. Python 3.7.

```
`def all_members_from_group(self, group_name, cnt):
            tk = 'token'
            code = '''
                var step='''+str(cnt)+''';
                var members=[];
                var count = 0;  
                var i = 0;
                while (i < 25 && step <= count) {
                    var c = API.groups.getMembers({group_id:'''+str(group_name)+''',offset:step+1000*i});
                    var member_id = c.items;
                    count = c.count;
                    var len_m = member_id.length;
                    var j = 0;
                    while (j < len_m) {
                        members.push(member_id[j]);
                        j = j + 1;
                    }
                    i = i+1;           
                }
                return members;
                '''
            code = urllib.parse.quote(code, safe='/', encoding='utf-8', errors=None)
            try:
                r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/execute?code='+code+'&access_token='+tk+'&v=5.92')
                a = r.json()

            except Exception as exc:
                text = str(exc)
                if 'limit' not in text:
                    time.sleep(3)
                    return
                else:
                    raise

            for member_id in a['response']:
                yield member_id
            time.sleep(3)
`
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас слишком большое количество операций - каждая атомарная операция скрипта это расход ЦП, поэтому во избежание использования "бесплатных мощностей" ВКонтакте лимитирует итоговую стоимость алгоритма. Например, циклы while, вложенные друг в друга, почти гарантируют натыкание на этот лимит при больших количествах итераций.

Насколько я понимаю, вы хотите через метод execute быстрее собирать членов группы, в таком случае вы можете создать следующую хранимую процедуру и вызывать её из своего кода:

```
var communityId = Args.community;
var offset = parseInt(Args.offset);
var iters = 25;
var membPerRequest = 1000;

var allIds = [];
var req_params = {
    "group_id": communityId,
    "sort": "id_asc",
    "offset": offset,
    "count": membPerRequest,
    "v": "5.92"
};

var i = 0;
var stop = false;

while (i < iters && stop == false) {
    req_params.offset = offset + i * membPerRequest;

    var items = API.groups.getMembers(req_params).items;

    if (items.length == 0 || items.length < membPerRequest) {
        stop = true;
    }

    allIds = allIds + items;

    i = i + 1;
}

return allIds;
```